# Disable table view cell selection after clicking alert action

Tags: swift, action, cell, disable

The main goal of the question is that after clicking the Off_shelve action, the selected cell will be disabled and turn the alpha to different color, letting the user know this cell not available. In addition, if the user click on the On_Shelve action, the selected cell will be accessible again.

Is this feasible ?

[image: Simulator Image]

Comment: Yes , this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

Get the `cell` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MyTableViewCell {
         // DO whatever you want here with the selected sell.
    }
}
```

In your case do the changes on the button click action from the `Alert`. Simple.